# Can not download curl

Tags: wget, curl, ssl, download

I was trying to download "curl", but could not do so. As far as I could tell, I did not have the problem last time.

```
$ wget https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.52.1.tar.gz
--2017-02-18 16:32:21--  https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.52.1.tar.gz
Resolving curl.haxx.se... 80.67.6.50, 2a00:1a28:1200:9::2
Connecting to curl.haxx.se|80.67.6.50|:443... connected.
ERROR: certificate common name `anja.haxx.se' doesn't match requested host name `curl.haxx.se'.
To connect to curl.haxx.se insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
Unable to establish SSL connection.
```

I tried to download it to my Mac, and transfer it to via Cyberduck, 
but met another message :
 "connection failed Indicated packet length 1684366188 too large." 
the same things happened when I attempted to transfer untared folder. 
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

macOS comes with `curl` as `/usr/bin/curl`.

```
$ /usr/bin/curl -O https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.52.1.tar.gz
```

This seems to work on my MacBook Air, from a terminal.

You could also try using the `--no-check-certificate` option with `wget`, as kindly suggested by the message from `wget`.

Comment: Yes, I could download with "--no-check-certificate", sorry that I did not realize that  "use `--no-check-certificate'" means an option for wget ... Tks!

Comment: @Jun If an answer solved your question, don't forget to accept it by clicking the pipe icon on the left. It is a reward to the answerer, and helps the others to differentiate the solved and yet unsooved problems.